# Converting Font Designs in an EPS to TTF or other Font Format

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, fonts, eps, ttf

I [downloaded a font](https://www.freepik.com/free-vector/shade-text-effect_11257517.htm#page=1&query=font&position=41) that is packaged as an EPS file but cannot figure how how to install the font into my OS or into Adobe Photoshop.

Is there an automated way to convert the EPS file into a format that can be installed directly into the OS (Windows/Mac)? I prefer a standalone software or online too, but have access to Adobe Illustrator as well if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In fact, that file **is** a string of **live type** with merely some **appearance panel** settings...

[image]

If you wish to apply the same *Appearance* to  different text, you can create a [**Graphic Style**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/graphic-styles.html) and then reapply the *appearance* to other text strings. The *actual* font in use is your choice entirely.

The purpose of that file is **not** to provide a "font". It is to provide an "effect" or appearance to reuse.

I'd also point out that **without** the separate, background, rectangles that appearance for the type is much less impressive...

[image]

.... And, no, you can't create a "font" with the applied Appearance Panel fills.